# Second monitor detected but no signal on Lenovo P16 Gen 2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I've been struggling with this problem for a while and been trying out different suggestions but none have worked yet, so I'll ask here!

I run a Lenovo P16 Gen 2 and use its monitor and want to use a second monitor with HDMI. (Using DP is not a possibility, because the one DP port is already taken). Ubuntu recognizes the second monitor in the display settings, with name and resolution, but the monitor receives no signal. I did get a signal when I have first gotten this laptop and it still hat Windows on it is not the cable or port, that is broken.

I run Ubuntu 22.04.1 (kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic) currently not using the proprietary display drivers by Nvidia.

It's maybe worth noting that a co-worker suggested downgrading my kernel to 5.15.0-57 and using Nvidias driver version 510 and having secure boot disabled, which seems to work for him, but i got stuck either not being able to boot at all, or after the downgrade not having network drivers anymore.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and more information will be delivered as needed.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: My system will not boot after installing the recommended driver. I will have to get into grub and purge it to boot again.

Comment: It is very uncommon. We don't know what is the Nvidia hardware, which driver you are trying to install, etc. Normally Nvidia drivers work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue with Lenovo P16 Gen1 and the same Ubuntu/kernel version (Ubuntu 22.04.1 (kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic)).

The previous kernel (Ubuntu 22.04.1 (kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic)) is able to support external monitor with usb-c docking station.

I tried multiple kernels after the above, even with kernel 6.2, the support to external monitor is gone.

I am not sure what's the change from 5.15.0-57-generic to 5.15.0-58-generic

Comment: Thank you for your post.  Listing all the kernels you tried might be helpful to those searching for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of work in the issue, I have followed the chatGPT recommendation with the procedure that made things work. I means, accidentally is working, for sure there is an issue, but it seems for now I can get back to my things.

Procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-525

sudo reboot now
```

During the startup the second display cloned the image from the main display:

the result:

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Apr 7 17:57:00 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17 Driver Version: 525.105.17 CUDA Version: 12.0 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
| | | MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 NVIDIA RTX A200... Off | 00000000:01:00.0 On | N/A |
| N/A 38C P8 8W / 60W | 114MiB / 8192MiB | 30% Default |
| | | N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: |
| GPU GI CI PID Type Process name GPU Memory |
| ID ID Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| 0 N/A N/A 2756 G /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg 113MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have noticed that the package damaging my system is: nvidia-dkms-525-open

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but there is still an issue:

```
[  159.738770] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  159.947189] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  170.385078] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.385194] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.385276] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.410816] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.410950] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.411041] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.464798] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.464926] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[  170.465016] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

Comment: Since you have a ton of errors I would say it is still not working. Have you searched for that error? What does it mean how to fix it?